# how to make cmakelists.txt compile cpp that uses functions and classes declared and implemented in some other place

Tags: c++, cmake, header-files

I have some functions classes defined in 2 header files and implemented in their cpp files in some folder. I use them for some cpp program (let's call it **cpp1.cpp**) that is located in the same dir. let's call that **dir1**.

Now my issue is: 
I have another **dir2** on the same level of **dir1** that has it's own **CMakeLists.txt** inside which I am trying to compile another cpp file (let's call it **cpp2.cpp**) located in **dir2**. This new cpp uses or rather should use some of the functions and classes declared and defined in the **dir1** header and cpp files. 
In my **cpp2.cpp** I am doing :

```
#include "header1_from_dir1.h"
#include "header2_from_dir1.h"
```

which is giving me this error:
error: 'func_name' was not declared in this scope func_name(param1)
                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~

when I try to include it with relative paths it compiles and works fine:

```
#include "../dir1/header1_from_dir1.h"
#include "../dir1/header2_from_dir1.h"
```

why is this happening ? how can I modify the CMakelists.txt to correctly 'see' the functions defined in **dir1** ?

in CMakeLists I have in short:

```
include_directories(../dir1)
add_executable(cpp2 cpp2.cpp ../dir1/cpp_header1.cpp ../dir1/cpp_header2.cpp)
target_include_directories(cpp2 PUBLIC ./dir1)
target_link_libraries(some_library_from_another_place)
install(TARGETS cpp2 DESTINATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/${TARGET_LOCATION})
```

dir structure:

```
.
|-- dir1
|   |-- bin
|   |-- build 
|   |-- header1_from_dir1.h
|   |-- header2_from_dir1.h
|   |-- cpp_header1.cpp
|   |-- cpp_header1.cpp
|   |-- cpp1.cpp       // this uses functions and clases from above files
|   `-- CMakeLists.txt // this is for above cpp1.cpp
|-- dir2
|   |-- bin
|   |-- build
|   |-- cpp2.cpp // this uses functions and clases from    
                 // dir1/cpp_header1.cpp
|   `-- CMakeLists.txt // this is for above cpp2.cpp and have briefly 
                       // described its contents
```

Comment: `target_include_directories(cpp2 PUBLIC ./dir1)` - didn't you mean to `target_include_directories(cpp2 PUBLIC ../dir1)` or better `target_include_directories(cpp2 PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../dir1)`

Comment: I would say ../dir1 is right since I have a script for compiling/building and I have tried with ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../dir1 with the same error message

Comment: What is your directory/file structure? Can you show/draw it? Where is `dir1` (or are there two `dir1`?) Try`target_include_directories(cpp2 PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dir1)` Where is this CMakeLists.txt? Is it inside dir1 or inside dir2 or in root?

Comment: Why are you calling `*include_directories()` twice? Those calls are redundant, in this example.

Comment: @squareskittles
yes you are right, although the removal does not clear the main issue.
I should've stated I am not so advanced in the art of cmake use as you probably have already seen.

Comment: @John11 KamilCuk's suggestion is correct, just be sure you re-run CMake *from scratch* by clearing your cache (deleting the CMakeCache.txt file).

Comment: @squareskittles, in my build script i remove both the build and the bin folders, so that I have already done.

Answer (score 1):

From [target_include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html) documentation:

> Relative paths are allowed within the INSTALL_INTERFACE expression and are interpreted relative to the installation prefix.

So relative paths are not what you want. You need to specify absolute paths for it to interpret properly for compilation. Use `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` for specifying a relative path from current source directory.

Comment: I have switched to using CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR, but the result is the same. the message call shows the correct path on either way of usage.
On the other hand, removing the needed files from the include_directories does print me it cannot find the included header file, as expected. The error I see I only interpret it as it could not find the object that has the function ... does this sound right ?

Comment: `it could not find the object that has the function` - you didn't source `cpp1.cpp`, inspect object files. To be honest, why don't you link with the library from dir1? I would just to `target_link_libraries(cpp2 PUBLIC cpp1)` asuming `dir1/CMakeLists.txt` does `add_library(cpp1)` in a similar fashion as in dir2..

Answer (score 0):

> how can I modify the CMakelists.txt to correctly 'see' the functions defined in dir1 ?

You can modify the project in the following manner:

## Project structure:

```
 ┣ dir1
 ┃ ┣ test.cpp
 ┃ ┗ test.h
 ┣ dir2
 ┃ ┣ CMakeLists.txt
 ┃ ┗ cpp2.cpp
 ┗ CMakeLists.txt
```

## Root

CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(test)
add_subdirectory(dir2)
```

## dir1

test.h

```
#pragma once
void hello();
```

test.cpp

```
#include "test.h"
#include <iostream>

void hello()
{
    std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
}
```

## dir2

CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_executable(cpp2)

target_sources(cpp2 PRIVATE cpp2.cpp  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../dir1/test.cpp)
target_include_directories(cpp2 PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../dir1)
```

cpp2.cpp:

```
#include <test.h>

int main()
{
    hello();
}
```

A better way could be to make a library from `dir1`, export it, and import in `dir2/CMakeLists.txt`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: unfortunatelly I am forced to keep the CmakeLists.txt in both dir1 and dir2 since they are both building different apps. This is part of a much larger project.
I was thinking too that creating a library would be a better way

Comment: You can keep the files in both directories. Just to make sure to add a new target `cpp2` in the `dir2/CMakeLists.txt` to the existing targets.

Comment: yes I have the new target added as:
add_executable(cpp2 cpp2.cpp ../dir1/cpp_header1.cpp ../dir1/cpp_header2.cpp)

what is that command target_sources ? I seem to nob be abel to find it on cmake doc site.

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_sources.html